# Nativescript timed service or thread for geolocation tracking

Tags: multithreading, service, geolocation, nativescript

I need to create looping thread or timed service for getting latitude and longitude especially if it changes. What way should I proceed with this one. I'm currently using nativescript-geolocation plugin (https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-geolocation).

Answer (score 0):

When you follow the [link](https://github.com/nsndeck/locationtest) in the thread you will see the whole example code on github.

You can get the current location by doing this:

```
var location = geolocation.getCurrentLocation({desiredAccuracy: 3, updateDistance: 10, maximumAge: 20000, timeout: 20000}).
then(function(loc) {
    if (loc) {
         // Your code here
    }
}, function(e){
    console.log("Error: " + e.message);
});
```

When you want to keep updating it, you can use:

```
var watchId = geolocation.watchLocation(
function (loc) {
    if (loc) {
        // Your code here
    }
}, 
function(e){
    console.log("Error: " + e.message);
}, 
{desiredAccuracy: 3, updateDistance: 10, updateTime: 1000 * 20}); // should update every 20 sec according to google documentation this is not so sure.
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is just what I was looking for!